# Which method is the best for starting the bot in discord.py? login() and connect() vs start() vs run()

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So, to connect the bot to [`discord.py`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html), there are several methods:

- [`discord.Client().login()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.login) + [`discord.Client().connect()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.connect)
- [`discord.Client().start()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.start)
- [`discord.Client().run()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.run)

---

What is the difference between them and which one is the best for running the bot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the [official documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) is very clear:

- [`start()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.start) is shorthand coroutine for [`login()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.login) + [`connect()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.connect).
- [`run()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.run) is a blocking call which means that

  > This function must be the last function to call due to the fact that
  >   it is blocking. That means that registration of events or anything
  >   being called after this function call will not execute until it
  >   returns.

There is no *"best"* method. If you want a synchronous execution, go for `run()`. `start()` (or `login()` + `connect()`) are more suitable for asynchronous executions.

**Example with `run()`**

With `run()` you don't have to manage any event loop:

```
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(start(*args, **kwargs))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    loop.run_until_complete(logout())
    # cancel all tasks lingering
finally:
    loop.close()
```

**Example with `start()`**

According to the docs, `start()` is

> a blocking call that abstracts away the event loop initialisation from
>   you.

This means that you need to place `start()` in an event loop.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(client.start('TOKEN'))
```